# How to config IDEA to support Multi-Release Jar development

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-9, multi-release-jar

I am learning MRJar and trying to create a sample example which has folder structure as follow, both java folder and java9 folder are marked as source root

```
└───main
    ├───java
    │   └───com
    │       └───test
    │               App.java
    │               DefaultVersion.java
    │
    ├───java9
    │   └───com
    │       └───test
    │               DefaultVersion.java
    │
    └───resources
```

IDEA complaining about duplicate class which is expected as it has duplicate classes under source root. But is there a way to config IDEA to support MRJar development? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not supported at the moment. Please vote for this request:
***[IDEA-168946](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168946/Add-support-for-building-Java-9-multi-release-jars) Add support for building Java 9 multi-release jars***.